# MongoDB : Hint with multiple columns in java query example

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java

In a collection subject, in which the documents have social,maths and english as fields. If I need to provide a hint to the following find query, how do I do it?

```
db.subject.find({maths : 30, social :10,english : 20});
```

Comment: Hints are provided using index names. You didn't tell us what indexes you have, or if you have any.

Comment: @ChristianP You can actually supply an index specification like: `{d:1, c:-1}` to hint which none of the answers below have said

Comment: @Sammaye you are correct, as always. I forgot to mention that in my comment, but the answers quickly pointed that out, so it was redundant for me to write it :)

Comment: @ChristianP I have indexes but cant we specify hints using fields rather than the index names?

Comment: You can also specify hint using fields (look at the answers).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, I haven't tested it :

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("maths", 30)
                     .append("social",10).append("english",20);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query).hint(new BasicDBObject(index , 1));
```

Comment: what is index here in the hint?

Comment: The index which you want to use for query !

Comment: How do i add hint to the aggregate query rather than a find query?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint)

db.subject.find({maths : 30, social :10,english : 20}).hint({maths : 1})
or any other index

Comment: i need to add multiple fields to the index, when i do so it is throwing bad hint error

Answer (score 0):

I had created index from command line. I tried this from Java,

```
Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("maths").is(30));
searchQuery.withHint("index_name");
```